# Как в Python3 выглядит шаблон проектирования с несколькими интерфейсами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Как я понял множественное наследование не есть хорошо.

Лучше использовать композицию.

Как работает композиция, я вроде как разобрался.

А что такое использование нескольких интерфейсов?

Или наследование от нескольких интерфейсов...

Вот цитата из Wikipedia:

> Можно заметить, что интерфейс, с формальной точки зрения, — это просто чистый абстрактный класс, то есть класс, в котором не определено ничего, кроме абстрактных методов.

Второй вопрос в Python3 это так и есть?

То есть я могу наследоваться, от нескольких абстрактных классов?

Comment: Вы же можете сами это проверить. Создать 2 абстрактных класса, создай третий класс, родителями которого будут первые 2. 6 строк кода.

Comment: Конечно можно. Проверьте сами. Как заметил @МихаилМуругов, это не займёт много времени.